# Как дождатся выполнения AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно дождатся выполнения `AlertDialog` и получить из него `return true` или `return false`, например нажимаю на кнопку `Отмена` должен вернутся `false`, но сейчас `AlertDialog` появляется и возвращается, до нажатия кнопкок. Вот код

```
public static Boolean Vebor_server(final Context context, final boolean ok) {
    Voider.Log(context,"Vebor_server", "Start");

    final Boolean[] temp = {false};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(getServerUpdate(context), -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int item) {
                                String UrlServer = getServerUrl(getIdaVisibleServers(item));

                                SharedPreferenses.setActivityServer(UrlServer);

                                temp[0] =true;

                                dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).setNeutralButton("Обновить",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            temp[0] =(Vebor_server(context ,true));

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).setTitle("Доступные сервера");

            if(!ok) builder.setCancelable(false);


            builder.show();


    return temp[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно создать интерфейс

```
public interface DialogListener{
        void dialogResult(boolean result);
    }
```

Далее добавляете в метод еще один параметр

```
public static void Vebor_server(final Context context, DialogListener listener, final boolean ok)
```

Обратите внимание что метод стал `void`

И само тело

```
.......
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(getServerUpdate(context), -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int item) {
                            String UrlServer = getServerUrl(getIdaVisibleServers(item));

                            SharedPreferenses.setActivityServer(UrlServer);
                            if (listener != null) {
                                listener.dialogResult(true);
                            }


                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            if (listener != null) {
                                listener.dialogResult(false);
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).setNeutralButton("Обновить",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            if (listener != null) {
                                listener.dialogResult(true);
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).setTitle("Доступные сервера");

            if (!ok) builder.setCancelable(false);


            builder.show();
......
```

Comment: Я не очень понимаю интерфейсы, вернее совсем не понимаю...

Comment: Или, вернее , мысль есть попробую

Comment: Стоит разобраться и понять, это широко используется, особенно в андроиде

Comment: Может ты поможешь разобратся? расскажи что происходит нормальным языком!) Ну вот создался интерфейс, передался в функцию окошка оки, функция нечего не возвращает, но как ждут ее завершения? Дальше, по кнопкам идет присвоение в этот самый интерфейс, пока не очень понятно         void dialogResult(boolean result); что это:), его назвали интерфейс, но он как я понел некуда не ведет принемает boolean, а что с ним делает??? брр...

Comment: И как он влияет на все это)

Comment: Я встречал эти интерфейсы часто но никак не понимаю их работы...

Comment: А никто и не ждёт, это как событие , вызовет метод dialogResult у того интерфейса который передадите в метод в момент нажатия кнопки диалога

Comment: Просто почитайте про калбэки с примерами простыми

Comment: Хорошо, но где этот самый метод dialogResult, как вы сказали нажали кнопку он его вызвал но кто он, в него код не впишешь.. А хотя понел, это что-то типо переменной да? Тоесть нажали на кнопку сменился в нем на false или true и я могу узнать так? но я его узнаю тогда когда никто не будет собиратся ждать ответа...

Comment: Ну вы в метод показа диалога должны передать реализацию интерфейса, просто попробуйте , студия вам все сделает.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сразу после показа диалога возвращаете результат, нужно либо подождать пока пользователь закроет диалог и потом возвращать, либо написать асинхронный код (с использованием callback)

Comment: Как сделать? Примерно

Comment: Но вы правильно сказали нужно дождатся пока диалог закроется,  но как

Comment: Где ваш пример с callback, я почитал на примере javascript, c, это то что надо! но не нашел примера под Java...

Comment: Нашел только это, http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Handler.Callback.html#handleMessage%28android.os.Message%29 и то под handler, можно сделать в handler, но примера та нету там...

Answer (score 1):

Ваш функционал довольно сложный для простого `AlertDialog`. Я бы посоветовал использовать [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) вместо него.

Comment: Вот читаю я  `Начиная с Honeycomb в Android появились фрагменты (Fragments), которые позволили повторно использовать в приложении части его пользовательского интерфейса и логику. Методы showDialog и dismissDialog класса Activity были объявлены устаревшими. Им на замену пришли DialogFragments.` Тоесть они не будут работать в андроиде 2.3, это плохо...

Comment: Для этого есть support library, ссылка в ответе на класс, который можно использовать начиная с Android 1.6

Comment: Тоесть можно запихнуть новый класс в `android` приложение и его использовать на более устарелых устройствах???

Comment: Не класс, а подключить библиотеку   
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html   
и пользоваться ее классами на здоровье.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поробывать сделать таким образом.

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(getServerUpdate(context), -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int item) {
                            String UrlServer = getServerUrl(getIdaVisibleServers(item));

                            SharedPreferenses.setActivityServer(UrlServer);

                            temp[0] =true;

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            //вызвать какой-то метод из активити специально созданный для обработки закрытия диалога по клику в нем.
                            //пример: <NameOfActivity>.this.doSmth();
                    }
                })
```

Comment: И как это? использовать, нее совсем не то, этот код вызывается из post который выбирает сервера, если сервер не выбран, то он ждет пока его выбирут, когда выбрали пост продолжает свою работу но уже с выбранным сервером...

Comment: но вызывается dialog.dismiss();, после которого диалог закрывается, вот тогда и выполняйте то, что вам надо.

Comment: Мне надо дождатся выбора сервера, но!

Comment: Он показывает диалог, и сразу выводит return false....

Comment: У вас странное строение программы, если честно. Вам проще убрать return, а оставшуюся часть кода перенести в функцию, которая будет вызвана из диалога.

Comment: Хм, что говорите не пойму, вы даже кода не знаете, и он не странный, нет не проше, этот выбор присутствует в двух местах, функция post везде, и я вам сказал что если сервера нету, вызывается окно это, а если есть не вызывается, и  что предложите...

Comment: Предлагаю вам пересмотреть логику поведения программы, вернее алгоритм может и правильный(не уверен), но реализация не учитывает тонкости системы. Вам надо сделать две ветки поведения, если вызван диалог и если нет, если вызван, то развитие продолжается через метод вызваный в диалоге, если нет, то как-то иначе или через тот же метод, но с другими параметрами, вот и все.

Comment: Ага, так у меня раньше и было:( И это не устраивает...

Comment: Ладно, пока попробую DialogFragment

Comment: Да система тут черезчур тонкая:) Это вам не c++ или php)